# How to avoid selling app to iPad 3 (or earlier)?

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to enable selling of my iPad app only for iPad 4 and later because it does not run fluently on an iPad 3.

Since Apple gives us no direct way to choose which device I can sell my app, the only ways to achieve this is via indirect methods like minimum iOS version support or so called required device capabilities.

However, it seems that there is no way to make a distinction between iPad 3 and iPad 4.

iOS 9, for instance, is supporting iPad back to 2nd generation.

Comment: Any particular reason why your app doesn't work fluently on iPad 3? Can you distinguish between iPad 3 and iPad 4 using the so called required device capabilities ?

Comment: check this link to see if you can exploit any of the device capabilities :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Comment: iPad 3 and iPad 4 have identical device capabilities.

Comment: A better question might be: "My app doesn't run particularly well on iPad 3 and I've found <feature(s)> to be the bottle neck. I've tried <this> to optimise it, but how can I optimise it more please?"

Comment: @user2473779: it does not run well on iPad3 because it is too much CPU intensive :(.

Comment: What not run fluently on iPad3? Can you write?

Comment: @James Webster: you are right, but for the moment trying to optimize more is not an option, that's why I'd like to know if I can avoid people having an iPad 3 to buy my app.